# Performing two authentication commands only if neither fail in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to register a user in Firebase, AND add that user to a "users" collection with additional fields. When registering a user, I only want these commands to execute if BOTH of them are successful. For example, I don't want to register a user in Firebase if the user fails to be added to the users collection. But I also don't want the user to be added to the users collection if the firebase createUser function fails.

```
func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String, username: String) {
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [self] result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to register with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            
            let data = ["email": email,
                        "username": username.lowercased(),
                        "fullname": fullname,
                        "uid": user.uid,
                        "listOfUserActions": listOfUserActions]
            
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .setData(data) { _ in
                    self.didAuthenticateUser = true
                }
        }
    }
```

The way I have this set up right now, if the user was added to FirebaseAuth but the post to "users" failed, wouldn't this just break the app if I have functionality depending on the "users" collection?

Comment: if not into Firebase, but maybe your register func should return Bool, and only return true if both worked. You can then react on that in the setup / views.

Comment: But then the problem is if FirebaseAuth createUser succeeds on the first attempt but insertion into the collection fails, then registration will fail but the user will still be added into FirebaseAuth. Then any future registration attempts would also fail because the user already exists in auth.

Comment: how do you check if the 2. step insertion into the collection fails? If it does, can you revoke the FirebaseAuth?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a combination of the methods from the createUser and setData methods to make sure that both of those operations succeed before setting didAuthenticateUser to true.

Here's the modified code:

```
func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String, username: String) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [self] result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to register with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let user = result?.user else { return }
        
        let data = ["email": email,
                    "username": username.lowercased(),
                    "fullname": fullname,
                    "uid": user.uid,
                    "listOfUserActions": listOfUserActions]
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
            .document(user.uid)
            .setData(data) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to set data with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                self.didAuthenticateUser = true
            }
    }
}
```